# How to send referer using Meta refresh on all browers?

Tags: html, refresh, referer

I want to redirect a webpage to a destiation WITH a referer. The straight forward solution is:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=example.com" /></head><body></body>
```

The problem is, this works in Chrome, Safari, but does not work in IE and FF because these browsers don't send referer. What can I do to accomplish the task, because the destination require an referer in order to process.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a javascript redirect based on automatic form submission.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id="redirect" action="//example.com" method="get"></form>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("redirect").submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried PHP header('Location:example.com') and it works. I will see if it is stable or not because someone said it may not work sometimes.

Comment: `header('Location: //example.com');` in PHP would indeed be a better way, and as far as I know is 100% reliable as it sends a HTTP level redirect code. You didn't mention in the question that you were using PHP :)

Also, worth adding an `exit();` after the `header();` call in php so that no further code is executed after the redirect.